# Events when binding data to the gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

What are the events will occur when Binding data to the Gridview ?

Comment: not sure why this is getting upvotes, a quick google search would have answered this. an upvote is a question that "shows research effort; it is useful and clear"

Comment: This is a documentation request, not a "*...practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.*" (from the [faq]).  It would be better if you could explain why you need to know this, what exactly you are trying to do, etc (you can [edit] your questions here).  You would probably also get more relevant answers to your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

There are many, Few are listed below. You can read complete list of GridView events here and check what you need. [**GridView Events**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx)

```
DateBinding 
DataBound
RowCreated
RowDataBound
```